# How to get rid that my yahoo account is sending e-mails itself

Tags: account-management, yahoo-mail

My yahoo account is sending e-mails to all those whose ID's are in my contact list. When i check the sent folder there is nothing sent to any one. How can i get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change your password. Some malware has stolen your password and is sending emails on your behalf.